# What is wrong with my HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Okay I am making a sample of navigation bar it's all fine except whenever the nested **li** is hovered the background doesn't fully cover the space.

My HTML code goes as :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>NavBar</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">About</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS code goes as :

```
html, body {
    margin: 100px;
    padding:0px;
    }
#nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #909090;
    font-familY: Courier;
    font-size: 19pt;
    color: #afc0ff;
    }
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #909090;
    }
#nav ul li:hover > ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    }
#nav ul li:hover {
    background: #808080;
    }
#nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
    }
#nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #260026;
    }
```

**My problem is:**

- I am not being able to make my nested li's background color cover up the whole area like you can see in Email that whole area is not hovered!
  [image: Display Of the Code]

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wn66zwhm/)**

Comment: I think its because your nested list is not displaying as block. You need to change it to display:block rather than inline-table.

Comment: @volumeone I did that see there in #nav ul li:hover > ul !

Comment: I meant your nested list. The list that is within the list. So #nav ul li ul li {display:block;}

Comment: @volumeone never mind, my mistake sorry for that !! yeah and that did solve the problem !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#nav ul ul li {
    display:block;
}
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nor1p95t/)**

Comment: wow thank you, you did helped me :), but that JSFiddle link is broken.